# R filtering columns

Tags: r

I am trying to filter my file based on two columns and if these are above a certain value to print a thrid column to a file.

I have got this-

```
sink(file='protein.txt'
print((x.csv[x.csv$unique>=2 & (x.csv$"log(I)")>=4, "Identifier"]), collapse ="\n")
```

I have run this code on my x.csv file, an example is below-

```
Unique log(I) Identifier
  2      3       BB8
  3      6       C3PO
  1      4       ATAT
  3      4       LK2
  2      7       HJ1
```

So it should print C3PO, LK2 and HJ1 to the sink I created.

However, it seems to work but when I check it I get this random line of text at the bottom of my file-

```
1266 Levels: DGH3, DH2, KLP1, 293 ... Z167
```

Now the total rows are 1274 so not sure where this has come from or why this has been included? Any help would be great

Thanks

EDIT-

Okay now I have this code-

```
write.table(x.csv[x.csv$unique>=2 & (x.csv$"log(I)")>=4, "Identifier"] , file= "protein.txt")
```

This gives me the correct result (A long list of proteins) but it also gives me numbers next to it, can I get rid of these?

Comment: That's what happens when you print a factor. Run `x = factor(letters); print(x[1])` to see. (Or, using your data, look what prints at the console when you do `print(x.csv[1, "Identifier"])`.) Rather than `sink` and `print`, maybe use `write.table` or `writeLines`, which are made for writing text to files in a standard format.

Comment: As in use write.table to create the new file then use writelines where print was?

Comment: No, as in `writeLines(x.csv[1, "Identifier"], con = 'protein.txt')`. It will create the file and write the data to it.

Comment: I have used write.table. Is there a way to remove the line number that also appears alongside it?

Comment: Yup. Use `row.names = FALSE`. See the documentation at `?write.table` for more details. Since you're writing just a single column, you might find the `writeLines` defaults better: `writeLines(x.csv[..., "Identifier"], con = 'protein.txt')` as in Rui's comment.

Comment: @Gregor I am getting an "invalid 'text' argument when I use writeLines

Comment: Ah, `writeLines` doesn't like factors. Try `writeLines(as.character(x.csv[..., "Identifier"]), con = 'protein.txt')`. (But at that point it's not any easier than `write.table`.)